# parsing output of stdout

Tags: python

I am trying to run few hadoop commands from python program...

For example if from command line, you do:

```
  bin/hadoop dfs -ls /hdfs/query/path
```

it returns all the files in the hdfs query path..
So very similar to unix

Now I am trying to basically do this from python.. and do some manipulation from it.

```
 exec_str = "path/to/hadoop/bin/hadoop dfs -ls " + query_path
 os.system(exec_str)
```

Now, I am trying to grab this output to do some manipulation in it.
For example.. count number of files?
I looked into subprocess module but then... these are not native shell commands. hence not sure whether i can apply those concepts
How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html probably `check_ouput` is what you want if it's stdout you want to capture.

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(["echo", "Hello World!"])
'Hello World!\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

`os.popen(exec_str)` will return a file type object on which you can subsequently call the `read` method.